# Is there any way to privately contact someone on SE?

Tags: support

I wanted to drop a quick private message to an SE member. Email would be fine. Is this possible?

Comment: Browsing meta and found your Qn. You could try posting a comment on one of their posts, then delete it a short time later.

Comment: Thanks @andy256, that's pretty much what I did in the end. This was a guy who had a low score/infrequent visitor and who'd asked a question about 6 months earlier. Wasn't sure if he was still using SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the member's profile and see an email address or URL, you can contact them via that.

Otherwise, no, there is no mechanism for private messages.

More info here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433